# How to redirect /page/index page to /page (and /page to /page/) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want /page/index to redirect to /page/ but

```
get '/page/index' => redirect('/page/')
```

is not working. Do I have to use redirect_to in index controller (I want to avoid it as it causes full request/reload of page) ? similarly I noticed that rails treats /page and /page/ as two different urls, how can I redirect /page to /page/ ? as

```
get '/page' => redirect('/page/')
```

is also not working (It is giving me infinite redirect problem).

Comment: What error are you getting? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection says your first example should work. Also, the kinds of redirects in your second example are best done on a server level, not an application level.

Comment: @sevenseacat - I got the first code worked, actually I also had get 'page/index' in routes.rb above where i was putting that code, now i have removed that. Also how to take care of the #2 ? I am using apache + phusion passenger ?

Comment: `/page` and `/page/` should be the same, pointing to the same controller action. How are you noticing differences?

Comment: @mihai - right, I meant my browser shows same content for /page and /page/ but search engines still treat /page and /page/ as two different urls something which bothers me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cause a full reload of the page, then you should not use "redirect" in your routes, as that simply issues a browser redirect. That would cause Rails to issue a 301 "Moved Permanently". That essentially means "there is a /page/index route but it's a mistake, we don't use it anymore, please go to /page instead and never come back here." If that is the case then that is what you want to do. If you're using Passenger and will continue to use Passenger, it would be more efficient to put an Apache redirect rule in the htaccess file.

It also seems strange that this is even an issue. How have /page/index, /page, and /page/ emerged in the wild as URLs that all point to the same index#index action? What is this index controller? The usual thing is to have, say, a PagesController that has your home page at index action. Then:

```
root to: 'pages#index"
```

and

```
<%= root_url %>
```

and

```
redirect_to root_path
```

Always go to the correct path and you don't have to worry about trailing slashes and such.